# Dimension of intersection of kernels of linear functionals

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, alternative-proof, symmetry

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space over a field $F$, and let $\varphi_1,\ldots,\varphi_k \in V^*$ be linearly independent. Then
$$
\dim(V) = k + \dim \left(\bigcap_{i=1}^k \ker(\varphi_i) \right).
$$

I have a proof which I provide below. I am interested to see different approaches.

---

*Proof:*

Define $T:V \to F^k$ by
$$
T(x)=\big(\varphi_1(x),\ldots,\varphi_k(x)\big).
$$
Then $\ker T=\bigcap_{i=1}^k \ker(\varphi_i)$.

By the Rank–nullity theorem,
$$
\dim (\ker T)+\dim\big( \operatorname{Image}(T)\big)=\dim V,
$$
thus it suffices to prove that $\dim \operatorname{Image}(T)=k$.

In order to shows this we shall use the following lemma:

**Claim:** There exist $x_1,\ldots,x_k \in V$ such that $\varphi_i(x_j) = \delta_{ij}$.

Then we have $T(x_j)=e_j$ form the standard basis of $F^k$. Thus $T$ is surjective as required.

**Question:** Can we prove $T$ is surjective without using the lemma of the $x_j$? Or maybe is there a different approach to proving the claim without defining an auxiliary map $T$?

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\ker\varphi_i=\langle\varphi_i\rangle^{\perp}$, that is, the orthogonal complement of the $1$-dimensional subspace spanned by $\varphi_i$ under the scalar product between $V^*$ and $V$ given by $\langle\varphi,x\rangle=\varphi(x)$.
Now
$$\bigcap_{i=1}^k\langle\varphi_i\rangle^{\perp}=\bigl(\sum_{i=1}^k\langle\varphi_i\rangle\bigr)^{\perp}$$
Since the $\varphi_i$ are linearly independent, we know the sum is direct and has dimension $k$, therefore the dimension of its complement is $\dim V-k$.

Comment: Thanks, that is an interesting approach, one you identify linear functionals with vectors, using an inner product (or any non-degenerate bilinear form).

Comment: @AsafShachar You already have one: $\langle\varphi,x\rangle=\varphi(x)$.