# basis for a dual basis

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm studying *Linear Algebra Done Right (3rd ed.)* by Sheldon Axler.  I've more or less completed the section on dual spaces in Chapter 3, and I have been doing the exercises.  Along the way I encountered some dual space $V'$ with a basis of linear functionals $\varphi_1, \dots, \varphi_m$, and I assumed that there exists a corresponding basis $v_1, \dots, v_m$ of $V$ for which the $\varphi$'s are the dual basis.  So I decided to prove this, and I came up with something, but it seems too long:

- Lemma: if $\varphi_1, \dots, \varphi_k$ are linearly independent, and their null spaces are respectively $N_1, \dots, N_k$, then $\dim ( N_1 \cap \cdots \cap N_k) = \dim V - k$.  Proof: first let $W$ be a complement of $N_1 \cap \cdots \cap N_k$ in $V$, and show that $\varphi_1|_W, \dots, \varphi_k|_W$ must be linearly independent, which meant that $N_1 \cap \cdots \cap N_k$ can't be too big.  Then show that $N_1 \cap \cdots \cap N_k$ can't be too small using $ \dim A \cap B = \dim A + \dim B - \dim A + B$.
- Applying my lemma to the $m$-dimensional basis $\varphi_1, \dots, \varphi_m$, WLOG note that $\dim (N_1 \cap \cdots \cap N_{m-1}) = 1$, so there exists some vector $v$ for which $\varphi_1(v) = \cdots = \varphi_{m-1}(v) = 0$.  But also by the lemma, $v \notin \operatorname{null} \varphi_m$.  Scale it so that $\varphi_m(v) = 1$ and call it $v_m$.
- Do the same to get the list $v_1, \dots, v_m$, which is the right length at least.
- Prove that $v_1, \dots v_m$ is linearly independent.  By contrapositive: assume that for some $j$, $v_j \in \operatorname{span}(v_1, \dots, v_{j-1})$.  But then $\varphi_j(v_j) = 0$, a contradiction.

I feel that there has to be a faster argument, because proving the existence of a dual basis for $v_1, \dots, v_m$ is quite fast—you can define some $\psi_1 \in \operatorname{span}(v_1)$ such that $\psi_1(v_1) = 1$, then create its linear extension $\varphi_1$ to all of $V$ such that it's zero on all the other $v$'s; do for $\varphi_1, \dots, \varphi_m$ in turn.  Would I be better off defining an isomorphism that maps $v_i \mapsto \varphi_i$ and just inverting it?

Comment: Hint: use reflexivity (the natural isomorphism $V\cong V''$). By the way, your lemma is useful in its own right, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4547609) are some alternative proofs.

Comment: thanks for putting me on the right track @blargoner.  and for the encouraging words about the lemma!